# Cross-platform deployment jobs in RunDeck

Tags: ansible, rundeck

I have a lot of Nix and Win environments in RunDeck.

I need to create a job like "Install monitoring service". This should install and configure some service both for linux and windows machines. installation script sure will differ.

But I'd like to have 1 logical job "Install monitoring service", but it should execute script1 for Linux and script2 for Windows, or something similar.

In Job definition there is a filter option, but I can't apply it to a concrete step, only for entire job.

It looks like I need a filter for a step: by some filter Windows step will be skipped for Linux instance, etc.

Comment: It's not as pretty, but can you put a "when" clause around the OS-specific steps keying off of the "ansible_os_family" variable? Or call an install_windows or install_redhat or install_debian role based on the "ansible_os_family"?  See this example for ideas: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/stackdriver-ansible-role/blob/master/tasks/main.yml

Answer (score 1):

I use a simple bash code to kick off the OS-specific code. This code is running on both Windows and Linux nodes. It will run `runLinuxFunction` on Linux nodes and `runWindowsFunction` on Windows nodes.

```
 #!/bin/bash
function windowsOrLinux() {
    if [ "$(expr substr $(uname -s) 1 5)" == "Linux" ]; then
        runLinuxFunction  #<------------Linux
        returnCode=$?
    elif [ "$(expr substr $(uname -s) 1 6)" == "CYGWIN" ]; then
        runWindowsFunction  #<------------Windows
        returnCode=$?
    else
        echo $(hostname) "Unknown OS type. Skip..."
        returnCode=1
    fi
    if [ $returnCode == 0 ]; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}
```

Note: all my windows nodes have Cygwin installed, so for Windows the OS type is be `cygwin`. you can use python if your windows doesn't support bash.